# Where can I use Windows 7 Math Input Panel?

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-office, equations, math-input-panel

Math Input panel that is integrated in new Windows 7 is very useful tool, I wonder where it can be used.

It can be probably used in Microsoft Office, but are there any other applications that support it?

I've tried WordPad, OpenOffice, and I think none of them work. It would be great if there was some free application that can use these equations or even some application that can export it as LaTeX, MathML or OpenOffice equations.

Is there any use for this application outside the Microsoft Office?

Answer (score 2):

Theoretically, any app that supports **MathML** (Mathematical Markup Language) can be used with the Windows 7 Math Input Panel. The Math Input Panel **only works** with programs that support MathML. Here are a few such apps: StarOffice, OpenOffice, Opera and Maple.

Comment: Please describe how can you use Math input panel with OpenOffice or Opera, I've tried it and it didn't work.

Comment: I'm using a mac right now, so I can't really say how to make it work.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a program that converts the MathML output into LaTeX.
Only by clicking "Insert" you will get the LaTeX into my Editor.

[www.inlage.com](http://www.inlage.com)